# Collapse Table Rows with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple table rows, some with a rowspan of 35, or 3, or none.

I was wondering a specific way to be able to collapse these rows.

I am using an HTML file and believe I can put a JS script in the HTML file using the script tags!

```
$('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

here is an example of the HTML code (please note I have tons of rows with varying rowspans)

```
  <div>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3">HEader Name Changes</th>
      <td>example1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>example2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>example3</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
```

This JS script seems to be have me on the right track!

For example

```
 <tr class="header">
   <th>This Changes</th>
    <td>Example1</td>
  </tr>
```

does not work

Comment: What is the issue? Does the code not work? If not what are the results you are getting compared to the result you are expecting?

Comment: Sorry...the code doesn't work. It could be that I am placing the script in the HTML file in the wrong place, or incorrectly using IDs within my HTML code.

Comment: @waterbottledotdot : share the markup

Comment: @PranavCBalan edited!

Comment: @waterbottledotdot : where is `.header` ??

Comment: this is where I am confused. where should I put .header

Comment: @waterbottledotdot : what are you trying to achieve ???

Comment: @waterbottledotdot Why do you have script targeting classes you don't have? In general. if you copy/paste script from somewhere else, make sure you understand what the script does before using it. The script shows what happens when you click on the element with `header` class. Its up to your requirement now if it is correct and amend the code as needed. Requirements should drive code, code should not drive requirements.

Comment: I am trying to be able to click on "Header name Changes" in order for it to collapse so we don't see the rest of the rows

Comment: @Fran how should I - or can I - add a class to my header?

Comment: Try it out and see what happens. Using jsfiddle, plunker or similar make that easier. If you stuck with what the code does check the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) for the function names, they have great descriptions and examples.

Comment: DO you think I should put the header class in the row?

Comment: @Fran please see my edit. This code, with the script within my <head> tag doesn't work